# Login does not work in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="mCSSv2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="MCSS.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
   <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
  
  <appSettings />
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnection" connectionString="LDAP://dibpak.com" />
    <add name="dib_constr" connectionString="Data Source=172.16.24.150;Initial Catalog=dib_MCSS;User Id=mps;Password=mpsdib;" providerName="Sql.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="oracle_constr" connectionString="Password=utils;User ID=utils;Data Source=dibhis216;" providerName="OraOLEDB.Oracle" />
    <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'" />
    <add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'" />
    <!--<add name="dib_constrsSql" connectionString="Data Source=172.16.204.37\sql2008;Initial Catalog=EMI;User Id=itih;Password=dib*1234;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
    <add name="dib_constrsSql" connectionString="Data Source=172.16.24.183;Initial Catalog=DIB;User Id=view_user;Password=dibuser@12345;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm"/>
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm"/>
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />

    <customErrors mode="Off" />

    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>

  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->

  
  
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <add value="SYS_Login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4199999999" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <applicationSettings>
    <mCSSv2.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_SendEmails_WebService1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://172.16.3.54/EmailBridge.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_FCC_FCCCUST" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://172.16.19.34:1781/FCCCUST.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_RPSAPI_TransactionAPI" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://172.16.25.189/RPSTransactionImportAPI/TransactionAPI.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_ca_uremit_api_ReceiveAPI" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://api.uremit.ca/ReceiveAPI.svc</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_WebReference_CallNadra" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://172.16.3.208:8090/CallNadra.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_com_xpresscheque_new_XMSSendTxnService" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://new.xpresscheque.com/XMWS/services/XMSSendTxnService</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_FCC1_FCCCUST" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://172.16.3.54:8013/fcccust.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="mCSSv2_RPSWS_TransactionAPI" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://172.16.24.41/RPSTransactionImportAPI/TransactionAPI.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </mCSSv2.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have an asp.net web application which works well on local host using visual studio and plsql database, and Active directory validation for login purpose.

Now the problem is that when i published it on IIS. The login page loads. If i enter the incorrect password it gives me an error saying 'Incorrect password' but if i enter correct password it reloads the page and doesnot proceed any further. Any idea why is this happening?

I tried enabling form authentication, binding and many more settings but to no use :I

Comment: You should give more exhaustive information like authentication type, web.config configuration, your login code

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the login code friend ill provide the web config